# JPA EntityManager no longer finding entities, even when reverted to code that used to work

Tags: java, maven, jpa, glassfish, entitymanager

I am creating a server with Glassfish, Jersey, and a MySQL database

My EntityManager used to work but now does not

Here's an example of a simple method that used to work but now does not

```
@GET
@Path("movie/{id}")
@JSONP
@Produces({"application/javascript", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Movie getMovie(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    EntityManager em = (EntityManager) context.getAttribute("em");
    Movie requestedMovie = em.find(Movie.class, id);
    return requestedMovie;
}
```

It now returns `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class: class data.entry.Movie, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.`

Bizarrely, it still does this even when I use git to roll my code back to a commit where I know it used to work.

Additionally, the code still works on my teammate's laptops.

The issue started when I attempted to add annotations to another class, and attempted to test it. This error started appearing. I then rolled my code back to previous commits to undo my changes, but I am still getting the error.

I have tried rebooting my laptop multiple times as well to no avail.

Any idea what could cause entity manager to stop being able to find entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by uninstalling/reinstalling glassfish

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove built file.
It's mostly related to IDE cache / build cache.

> Unknown Entity bean class: class data.entry.Movie, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.

And please check this too.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. I tried rebuilding the project to no avail. I also tried renaming the old project folder, and using git to reclone the entire thing. Still no dice. Any idea where there could be problematic caching?

Comment: Did you delete existing built file? (jar, classes, ....). If you're using intellij, try File > InvalidateCache/Restarts.

Comment: You can build by command line also, get rid of IDE dependent :D

Comment: I tried File > InvalidateCache/Restart and still not working